# Spark dataset type annotations support

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Given a simple case class with a type annotation `@Bar`:

```
case class Foo(
  field: Option[String] @Bar
)
```

converting a `RDD[Foo]` to a `Dataset[Foo]` fails at runtime with the following stack trace:

```
User class threw exception: scala.MatchError: scala.Option[String] @Bar (of class scala.reflect.internal.Types$AnnotatedType)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:483)
at ...
```

A ticket is open for this issue ([SPARK-27625](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27625)). However, is there a workaround?

Using spark 2.3.2

Comment: SPARK-27625 was fixed. I guess it will be available with Spark 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frameless library supports type annotations.